# mac installation go swagger error with the following message `open /usr/local/go/bin/swag: permission denied`

Tags: go, swagger

I run the following command to install swag and the error message is as follows.
I hope it helps.

```
MacBook-Pro~: go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag                                                                                                                                                                                   1 ↵  5434  14:55:27
go: found github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag in github.com/swaggo/swag v1.6.7
go: golang.org/x/text upgrade => v0.3.2
go: github.com/go-openapi/spec upgrade => v0.19.8
go: github.com/cpuguy83/go-md2man/v2 upgrade => v2.0.0
go: github.com/go-openapi/swag upgrade => v0.19.9
go: golang.org/x/tools upgrade => v0.0.0-20200612022331-742c5eb664c2
go: gopkg.in/yaml.v2 upgrade => v2.3.0
go: github.com/urfave/cli/v2 upgrade => v2.2.0
go: golang.org/x/net upgrade => v0.0.0-20200602114024-627f9648deb9
go: github.com/go-openapi/jsonreference upgrade => v0.19.3
go: github.com/go-openapi/jsonpointer upgrade => v0.19.3
go: github.com/PuerkitoBio/purell upgrade => v1.1.1
go: github.com/mailru/easyjson upgrade => v0.7.1
go get github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag: copying /var/folders/jm/s7qg764x5y93_2_x64qwlswm0000gn/T/go-build542960688/b001/exe/a.out: open /usr/local/go/bin/swag: permission denied
```

I installed go via the pkg package, and here are my environment variables.

```
MacBook-Pro  ~/Documents/goProjects/bin  go env                                                                                                                                                                                                         ✔  5439  15:40:42
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/usr/local/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/zhangyu/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/zhangyu/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/aaron/Documents/goProjects"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/jm/s7qg764x5y93_2_x64qwlswm0000gn/T/go-build760572234=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

How do I change the permissions, am I installing it incorrectly, or do I need to change the environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

It appears your `$GOPATH` is set to `/usr/local/go/`. Verify by running `echo $GOPATH` in the terminal.

`/usr/local/go` is usually owned by user `root`. You personal user is not allowed to write stuff there, hence the error.

You have a couple of options:

- Set your `$GOPATH` explicitly to a location you can read/write to. That should be something like [this] (https://gist.github.com/molivier/271bba5d67de1583a8e3). Note that I am not a Mac user and could not verify that this gist works.
- Unset the `$GOPATH` to use the default: https://rakyll.org/default-gopath/
- Allow your user to write to `/usr/local/go/`. I am not gonna discribe how to achieve this because you **should not do this anyway**.

If you have been working with `go` before make sure you copy the directories `/usr/local/go/bin`, `/usr/local/go/pkg` and `/usr/local/go/src` to your new `$GOPATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I added my environment variables, can you look at them for me again?

Comment: So: `unset GOBIN && go get -u github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag`